# Office Addin Taskpane not openend by starting debugging

Tags: visual-studio, office-js, office-addins, office-2016

My Office Addin is no more started and displayed in office 2016 desktop apps when I start a debug session in Visual Studio.
Time ago the Commands are added to the ribbon and the taskpane was opened automatically. All this worked before!?

Yes - I did clean the Wef folder and cleaned browser cache - no success.
***Any tipps what I can do?***

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes - I am using Visual Studio 2017 (Version 15.5.2).

Comment: Is the issue that your add in does not appear in the ribbon? Or that when you go to debug in VS it does not launch your addin? Try this, go into Excel and go to Options>Addins>scroll to Manage Addins>Choose COM addin>Go. Confirm that your Addin is listed and checked.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob H - But it is a Office.js add in - not COM.

Comment: Oh my mistake, didn't see the .js tag when I looked initially. Glad you got it resolved!

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem related to **ReSharper 2017.3**.
Once I supsended ReSharper - it all works as before.
*So - it is up to the ReSharper team to fix this... posted a bug there.*